# Spring boot aop around Datasource.getConnection not work, somebody any idea?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, spring-aop

Old spring XML config is working fine, my Aspect call everyone getconnection Invoke :

```
<bean id="connectionInterceptor" class="mypackage.ConnectionAspect">
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="connectionLifecycleAspect" ref="connectionInterceptor">
        <aop:pointcut
            expression="execution(java.sql.Connection javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(..)) "
            id="dataSourceGetConnection" />
        <aop:around method="aroundGetConnection" pointcut-ref="dataSourceGetConnection" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

My java class around get connection

```
public class ConnectionAspect implements Serializable {

private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ConnectionAspect.class);

    public Connection aroundGetConnection(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Connection connection = (Connection) joinPoint.proceed();
        setSessionUser(connection);
        return connection;
    }
```

Spring boot don't work, any metod not called when i call get Connection.
But spring service aop demo is working.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class ConnectionAspect implements Serializable {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(..))", returning = "connection")
    public Connection setClientIdentifier(Connection connection)
            throws SQLException {
        System.out
                .println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        return connection;


    }

    @Pointcut("execution(java.sql.Connection javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(..))")
    public void aroundConnection() {
    }

    @Around("aroundConnection()")
    public Object aroundConnection2(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Completed: " + joinPoint);
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }



    @Around("execution(java.sql.Connection javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(..))")
    public Object aroundConnection3(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("Completed: " + joinPoint);
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: **(1)** This is incomprehensible to me: _"Spring boot don't work, any metod not called when i call get Connection."_ Please explain: What does not work? Which method is not called? Any error messages? **(2)** Have you noticed that you have two classes/aspects with the exact same class name here? Could that be the problem? **(3)** Is any other XML configuration from your file containing AOP configuration being picked up by the application? **(4)** Does it work if you change `aroundGetConnection(..)` to exactly have the same signature (return type!) and content as e.g. `aroundConnection2()`?

Answer (score 0):

SpringBoot default use tomcat-jdbc as the DataSource implements.Then,the following code will be work fine.

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(..))", returning = "connection")
public Connection setClientIdentifier(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    return connection;
}
```